# Using a context manager for connecting to a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I wanted to create a `class` for database access in which the I want the programmer to have an option for using the class in a context manager (the `with` statement). So I tried with the following code:

```
class dbAccess:

    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.conn = sql.connect(fileName)
        self.c = conn.cursor()

    def __enter__(self, fileName):
        self.conn = sql.connect(fileName)
        self.c = conn.cursor()

    def __exit__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Now I also want the user to be able to use this outside of a context manager. Just like the file `open()`. So I want to know how I can know if `self.conn` is already connected to a database, so that when the user uses this, he/she does not run into a conflict? Basically, I want to do something like:

```
    def __enter__(self, fileName):
        if not alreadyConnected():
            self.conn = sql.connect(fileName)
            self.c = conn.cursor()
```

So how do I figure out the `alreadyConnected` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue with the above context handler fragment is that the `__enter__` method does not return the instance to the calling `with` block:

```python
with dbAccess(fnam) as db:
    assert db, "sorry, db is None"  # this will raise
```

Also the second `connect()` is redundant. A working context handler for `sqlite3` would look like so, also removing the need for a method like `alreadyConnected`(or, better, `already_connected`):

```python
from pathlib import Path
import sqlite3

class SQLite:
    """
    A minimal sqlite3 context handler that removes pretty much all
    boilerplate code from the application level.
    """

    def __init__(self, path: Path):
        self.path = path

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection: sqlite3.Connection = sqlite3.connect(self.path)
        self.connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        self.cursor: sqlite3.Cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        # do not forget this or you will not be able to use methods of the
        # context handler in your with block
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # just an example
    db_path = Path(".") / "local" / "twitter.sqlite"
    sql_statement = "select distinct author_id from tweets"

    # above context handler removes pretty much ALL boilerplate code
    # from application level code
    with SQLite(db_path) as db:
        db.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        for row in db.cursor:
            print(row["author_id"])

    # sqlite3 also offers a context handler, BUT
    # a) you have to manage row_factory and cursor repetitively in
    #    the application code...
    with sqlite3.Connection(db_path) as db:
        db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row        # boilerplate
        cursor = db.cursor()                # boilerplate
        cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        for row in cursor:
            print(row["author_id"])
    # b) and it does NOT close connections on __exit__
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(sql_statement)
    for row in c:
        print(row["author_id"])
```

Note that the `sqlite3` module offers `Connection` as a context handler right away, but with some drawbacks as shown in the code.